# Ubuntu: Process vfs-worker taking all CPU resources

Tags: ubuntu, process, django, mongodb, virtualenv

My Cloud9 (Ubuntu-based cloud IDE) began to be unresponsive after I tried to save some files (they didn't save to my cloud workspace). It shows 100% CPU utilization and a process that takes all CPU power.

Here is the error from which the 100% CPU utilizing vfs-worker process starts:

`Failed to write to 'settings.py'. Failed saving file ! : djangoserver/djangoserver/settings.py ERR: Error: EACCES, open '/home/ubuntu/workspace/djangoserver/djangoserver/settings.py'.`

Rights in `djangoserver` directory with `djangoserver/settings.py`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 25 15:21 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  147 Nov 25 15:33 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1990 Nov 25 15:21 settings.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2174 Nov 25 15:33 settings.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  303 Nov 25 15:21 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  399 Nov 25 15:21 wsgi.py
```

Rights in the parent directory:

[image]

The process causing this is:

`vfs-worker {"pi`

and it seems to be associated with the IDE (after killing it it displays `Reconnecting...` message). After killing it the process restarts itself with a different PID.

This might as well be a bug in the IDE based on the misspelled name. I tried restarting the whole IDE, but it comes back right after restart.

Before I dismiss this as a bug I would like to see if there could be other causes to this. I also have Python module **virtualenv** installed (not sure what it does) as a requirement for adding **MongoDB** support to **Django**. This might also be caused by virtualenv, which I added just recently according to this [tutorial](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the error was affecting only `djangoserver` directory in my workspace, the steps I took were:

1. Delete `djangoserver`. Even after deletion of the `djangoserver` folder I could see the IDE displaying a different error and still crashing on 100% CPU load:

`Failed to delete folder ‘testenv'. stderr maxBuffer exceeded..`

2. Restart workspace. By doing this the whole problem was solved.

Not sure what it was, it may be a bug in the IDE.